# Schedule JavaFX Application in Windows

Tags: java, javafx, windows-task-scheduler

I've GUI base JavaFX application. There are two buttons on it to perform specific functionality. One button used to send Inventory using HTTP Client to magento. I want to schedule this application on windows to run every 15mins. How to schedule it in way that when it runs, only 'Upload Inventory' button is clicked so that Inventory would be sent.

Answer (score 2):

Scheduled tasks should run in the background and the most they should do on a UI is show a notification that "hey I'm active again".  Certainly not show user windows (which is done typically to hand over control ***to the user***) and then reclaim control from the user by automatically starting to click things on behalf of that user.  Refactor your code to facilitate the function to run ***indepedently*** of the UI and schedule ***that***.

Comment: OK thanks Erwin. I had an idea of refactoring but both of manual execution and scheduled execution need to run parallel. i.e. With user interaction and scheduled task. Is there way to pass status of button as parameter so whenever scheduled task run, it only goes to 'Inventory Update'. 
OR I'd need separate program for scheduling?

Comment: Proper separation of concerns between the presentation layer ('V' and 'C' in an MVC architecture) and the business functions proper (anything closer to the 'M' in MVC as I understand it) implies that you can not have your business functions being aware in any way of things such as "button state".  I'm not going to cover all possible ways in which running tasks can communicate with each other, that would really go way too far.